# Join two SQL tables from diferent queries

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm trying to join these two queries. Can anyone help?

Query 1 -

```
SELECT provas.id, disciplinas.disciplina, disciplinas.grupo,salas.sala 
FROM provas, disciplinas, horarios, salas 
WHERE provas.id = provas.id AND provas.id_disciplina = disciplinas.id AND provas.id_horario = horarios.id AND provas.id_sala = salas.id AND provas.id_horario JOIN horarios ON ;
```

Query 2 -

```
SELECT dias.dia, meses.nome, horas.hora, minutos.minuto 
FROM horarios, meses, dias, horas, minutos 
WHERE horarios.id = horarios.id AND horarios.id_dia = dias.id AND horarios.id_hora = horas.id AND horarios.id_mes = meses.id AND horarios.id_minuto = minutos.id;
```

[Main table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cMy2k.png)

[Second Main table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2HJ0l.png)

I want to associate the "provas" table with the "horario" but the horario table has more foreign keys

provas = exams
horarios = scheudule

I want to join the shedule on the exams table, but the sheudule have more foreign keys for tables "days", "months", "hours" and "minutes"

[All involved tables](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8cBxW.png)

Comment: Please show us your table and your expected output.

Comment: First, find a tutorial that demonstrates how to do a proper JOIN. A proper JOIN does not contain a single comma.

Comment: what is the common column in these queries?

Comment: I'çç had some screenshots

Comment: Ken, oldschool joins have commas hahah

Comment: `SELECT provas.id, disciplinas.disciplina, disciplinas.grupo,salas.sala ,dias.dia, meses.nome, horas.hora, minutos.minuto 
FROM provas, disciplinas, horarios, salas, meses, dias, horas, minutos 
WHERE provas.id = provas.id AND provas.id_disciplina = disciplinas.id AND provas.id_horario = horarios.id AND provas.id_sala = salas.id AND provas.id_horario AND horarios.id_dia = dias.id AND horarios.id_hora = horas.id AND horarios.id_mes = meses.id AND horarios.id_minuto = minutos.id;;

`

Comment: I got it by myself, thank you anyway! :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try the following query. I didn't run this to make sure no syntax errors. But you can see the concept. You can join with a result set of a second query as shown below. I suggest you to consider the joins in your original query again. You may change the joins in my answer as it fits for your purpose.

```
SELECT ps.id, das.disciplina, das.grupo,s.sala 
FROM provas ps 
inner join disciplinas das on ps.id_disciplina = das.id
inner join horarios hs on ps.id_horario = hs.id
inner join salas s on ps.id_sala = s.id
inner join (
SELECT d.dia, ms.nome, h.hora, m.minuto, hs.id hsid
FROM horarios hs
inner join  meses ms on hs.id_mes = ms.id
inner join dias d on hs.id_dia = d.id
inner join horas h on hs.id_hora = h.id 
inner join minutos m on hs.id_minuto = m.id) zz on ps.id_horario = zz.hsid
```

Comment: Thank you, I apreciate your comment but I'm not "inner joins", I'm more of "Where id = id .. bla bla"

Comment: I don't know if you saw my comment but I've already done it by myself, anyway thank you alot

Answer (score 0):

My solution (I prefer this way):

```
 SELECT provas.id, disciplinas.disciplina, disciplinas.grupo,salas.sala ,dias.dia, meses.nome, horas.hora, minutos.minuto 
 FROM provas, disciplinas, horarios, salas, meses, dias, horas, minutos
 WHERE provas.id = provas.id AND provas.id_disciplina = disciplinas.id AND provas.id_horario = horarios.id AND provas.id_sala = salas.id AND provas.id_horario AND horarios.id_dia = dias.id AND horarios.id_hora = horas.id AND horarios.id_mes = meses.id AND horarios.id_minuto = minutos.id;
```